# How to access an element from complex json

Tags: arrays, json

​hello
From 2-3 days,iam stucked in a new problem,actually i have to retrieve information using 'api url' that retrieves complex json array which is just like this-

```
{"response":{"success":true,"result":{"id":"45203511","device_id":"62970","message":"Rs. 20.00 refunded in your Paytm wallet for your order on Paytm. Updated balance:Rs. 20.0. Queries? Visit Paytm.com\/care.","status":"received","send_at":0,"queued_at":0,"sent_at":0,"delivered_at":0,"expires_at":0,"canceled_at":0,"failed_at":0,"received_at":1507375388,"error":"N\/A","created_at":1507375388,"contact":{"id":"9209301","name":"VK-IPAYTM","number":"VK-IPAYTM"}}},"status":200}
```

I want to print an element from this json to console
"console.log (data);"
This code print whole array in console,but I have to print only "id" element.
please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

*"I have to print only "id" element"*

Your data is the nesting object, so to get any object property, you can do `object.property` or `object["property"]`. And here is an example, how to get `id` property:

```js
var obj = {"response":{"success":true,"result":{"id":"45203511","device_id":"62970","message":"Rs. 20.00 refunded in your Paytm wallet for your order on Paytm. Updated balance:Rs. 20.0. Queries? Visit Paytm.com/care.","status":"received","send_at":0,"queued_at":0,"sent_at":0,"delivered_at":0,"expires_at":0,"canceled_at":0,"failed_at":0,"received_at":1507375388,"error":"N/A","created_at":1507375388,"contact":{"id":"9209301","name":"VK-IPAYTM","number":"VK-IPAYTM"}}},"status":200}
console.log(obj.response.result.id)
```

Comment: **It shows error :-**

_train2.php:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined
    at Object.success (train2.php:23)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)_

**My whole script part is:-**

`<script type="text/javascript">
var position ={};
$.ajax({
  url:"my_api_url",
     type:"GET",
     success:function (data){
       console.log(data.response.result.id);
     }
   });
</script>`

**please help me!**

Comment: @Kalpitrathore, didn't you forget to parse your JSON using `JSON.parse(yourJSONHere);`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse